# In-script approval screen, keeps showing signatures for approval although it was already approved

Tags: linux, jenkins-pipeline, containers

I have jenkins container which runs pipeline, and fails on script approval:

```
Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.EnvironmentAction getEnvironment. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
[JobCompletedListener] Build result is: FAILURE
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.EnvironmentAction getEnvironment
```

Although I went to `in-scriptApproval` screen, and approved it, on the next run it shows them again.
The same job works perfectly on other VM Jenkins.

Comment: Are you running Jenkins in a container or does the Jenkins process miss the right to access scriptApproval.xml in Jenkins dir?

Comment: I'm running it as a container

Comment: Then run the container with a volume, e.g.: docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts

Comment: It's running with volume. BTW, scripts were already approved in that machine, but for some reason, these one are causing the problem

Comment: Can you take a look into the scriptApproval.xml if it is there?

Comment: I checked and it's there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the wrong UID and GID of the user. after I've changed it from jenkins to 1000 1000 recursively, issue solved.